# Failed to start Show Plymouth Boot Screen error while booting Ubuntu

Tags: plymouth

I am not able to boot. It is showing the same error in every boot:

[image: screenshot showing the error]

Comment: Something happened to your computer? Sudden power interruption?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that this is Ubuntu 20.04...

From the GRUB menu, choose Additional Options, then Recovery Mode, Root Access.

At the `#` prompt:

```
mount -o remount,rw /

sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

[image]

Choose the `ubuntu-logo` choice, then repeat the command with the `bgrt` choice.

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

Then reboot.

Comment: In my case, Lubuntu 20 04, it boots and says [ok] for Finished Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.Then nothing. With Alt-F1 I can go to tty1, but Lubuntu will not start in GUI. With Ctrl Alt F7 I get back to the Plymouth message, but no gui.

Comment: @Timo Please start a new question with all of the details that you can provide.

Comment: In my case issue was arised because of SELinux. To resolve it I removed string with selinux in the etc/default/grub , apply changes update-grub and restart my pc. It works then.  More info : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328085/failed-to-start-journal-service-ubuntu-doesnt-start

Comment: @arunpal SELinux doesn't belong in /etc/default/grub anyway. Who put it there?

Answer (score 0):

same problem on Linux mint 21.1. mostly physical problem, as memory card HDD bad connection. Remove memory cards and set again, remove HDD and set again.

if still this problem, keep pushing F3 when boot PC.