# Failed to start Journal Service (ubuntu doesn't start)

Tags: boot, 20.04, systemd-journald, selinux

I have Ubuntu 20.04. I decided to enable SELinux. I done only 3 strings successfully and reboot my pc:

```
1. sudo apt install policycoreutils selinux-utils selinux-basics
2. sudo selinux-activate
3. sudo selinux-config-enforcing
```

Unfortunately after this commands my Ubuntu doesn't boot. I have next errors:

```
systemd[1]: Failed to start Journal Service.
Dependency failed for Flush Journal to Persistent Storage
```

and many other errors:

```
FAILED Failed to mount Mount unit for logmein-host, revision 206.
Dependency failed for Service for snap application logmein-host.wetty.
Dependency failed for Service for snap application logme in-host.pytty. 
Dependency failed for Service for snap application logmein-host.logmein.
```

How to repair Ubuntu state? How to disable SELinux to boot Ubuntu normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to enter in recovery mode:

1. If you don't see grub screen, reboot your computer and press shift   multiple times.
2. Once you see grub screen select advanced options for Ubuntu
3. Choose the one with the recovery word in it and latest kernel version
4. Choose root
5. Mount / ( mount -o remount,rw /).
6. Remove any unwanted packages.
7. Finally reboot (type reboot in command line then press enter)
   Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I booted like root through recovery mode and remove string with selinux in the `etc/default/grub` apply changes `update-grub` and restart my pc. All works fine.

Comment: You're welcome!!!